# arranging files into numpy array

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I have many text files in a directory with numerical extension(example: `signal_data1.9995100000000001,signal_data1.99961` etc)

The content of the files are as given below

signal_data1.9995100000000001

```
-1.710951390504200198e+00
 5.720409824754981720e-01
 2.730176313110273423e+00
```

signal_data1.99961

```
-6.710951390504200198e+01
 2.720409824754981720e-01
 6.730176313110273423e+05
```

I just want to arrange the above files into a single .npy files after sorting the neumeric .extension as

```
array([[-1.710951390504200198e+00,5.720409824754981720e-01,2.730176313110273423e+00],
[-6.710951390504200198e+01,2.720409824754981720e-01,6.730176313110273423e+05]])
```

So same procedure i want to implement for many files of a directory.

I tried the loop as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
arr = [ ]
for file in glob.glob(./signal_*):
    arr.vstack('data', file)
```

However it doesnot give what i want as depicted above.So here i need help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error or an unexpected result? It is usually helpful to post what you see. Your variable arr is a list, not a numpy array. You can only use vstack with numpy arrays. And vstack doesn't take in strings as argument anyway.

Comment: What is the numeric extension: `.99961` or `1.99961`?

Comment: @Corralien it is 1.99961

Comment: @butterflyknife i get somekind of error

Comment: @Corralien i get result by using aa=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'./data/*')])  but i am unable to include a code which will sort the files and do np.vstack

Comment: @NilsWerner. Did you really read the question? Saving to a .npy file is not what the OP asked. He wants to reorganize his data before saving them in a .npy file. Please reopen.

Comment: It is the same question with the exact same data, by the same OP, just 3 hours earlier.

Comment: What is the problem with the answer of @NilsWerner in your previous question? (except if you have some numeric values greater than 10 in your filenames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an intermediate dict to collect data, sort it by `key` (numeric extension) before create your final array:

```
import pathlib
import numpy as np
import re

data = {}
for file in pathlib.Path().glob('signal_data*'):
    # get the numeric extension with a regex
    key = re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', file.name).group(0)
    data[key] = np.loadtxt(file)
    
arr = np.array([a[1] for a in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])])
```

Output:

```
>>> arr
array([[-1.71095139e+00,  5.72040982e-01,  2.73017631e+00],
       [-6.71095139e+01,  2.72040982e-01,  6.73017631e+05]])
```

Comment: Nice, you anticipated that OP probably wants the rows sorted by the numerical index :-P

Comment: @butterflyknife. The OP said *"after sorting the numeric extension"* :)

Comment: @sarmistabehera. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: sarmistabehera: @Corralien is too polite to mention it, but if their suggestion solved your problem, then good etiquette dictates that you upvote and accept it.

Comment: Thanks @Corralien...sorry for the delay....

Answer (score 1):

Please see my comment for the errors in your code.

```
import numpy as np
import glob

for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob("./signal_*")):
    if(i==0):
        arr = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',')
    else:
        new_arr = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',')
        arr = np.vstack((arr, new_arr))

arr
```

Output:

```
array([[-1.71095139,  0.57204098,  2.73017631],
       [-1.71095139,  0.57204098,  2.73017631]])
```

You can also read pandas.read_csv() to read in your array. I think it's supposed to be faster, but I didn't use that in the code above in case you don't have it.

Comment: why the result is repeated, its not like what is depicted in output

Comment: @sarmistabehera Because I pasted the same data in both files. It's only a test. Please try with your own files and let me know if it works. Please consider upvoting and accepting this answer if it worked for you.

Comment: d'oh! I didn't read the bit about sorting by the numerical extension. @Corralien's answer is better than mine.